# How to append new table into original table without overwriting original table?

Tags: mysql, r

I want to append new table to original(existing) table without overwriting original table. What is the query code for appending new table?

I have tried the following codes.

```
  ## choose one document from vector of strings
  file <- x[j]

  # read csv for file
  doc <- read.csv(file, sep=";")

  # indicate number of rows for each doc
  n <- nrow(doc)

  # create dataframe for doc
  df <- data.frame(doc_id = numeric(n), doc_name = character(n), doc_number = character(n), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  # loop to create df 
  for(k in 1:nrow(doc)){

    df$doc_id[k] <- paste0(df$doc_id[k])
    df$doc_name[k] <- paste0(doc$titles[k])
    df$doc_number[k] <- paste0(doc$no[k])

  }

  # query for inserting table to mysql
  query1 = sprintf('INSERT IGNORE INTO my_sql_table VALUES ("%s","%s","%s");', df[i,1],df[i,2],df[i,3])

  # query for appending table to my_sql_table
  query2 = sqlAppendTable(con, "doc", df)

# execute the queries
  dbExecute(con, query1)
  dbExecute(con, query2)

  print(j)  
} ## end of for loop
```

I also tried the following queries for appending, unfortunately, it didn't work.

`INSERT IGNORE INTO my_sql_table VALUES ("%s","%s");`

`INSERT IGNORE INTO tableBackup(SELECT * FROM my_sql_table);`

I expect to have appended new_table to original_table without deleting or overwriting the original table.

Comment: Using `IGNORE` is generally bad practise as it ignores all possible SQL errors which might be generated..

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) so we have a feeling for the data

Comment: But generally you could try ...`INSERT INTO table1 (<columns>) SELECT <columns> FROM table2 WHERE table2.id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM table1)`  note run it on a test database not your real data.. As this is a long shot and heavy guessing without tables structures and example data....

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for response. The thing is I have original_table that updates continuously, I want to append original_table to new_table. So in the end I will have information for two tables in new_table. (the column names are identical)

Comment: *"The thing is I have original_table that updates continuously, I want to append original_table to new_table."* Well then most likely a [TRIGGER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) is your best option